# Azure Blob to Azure SQL Database - Data Factory

Tags: azure, transformation, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a CSV file which contains Name and DOB of persons. I want to store it in Azure SQL database with an additional column of Age which has to be calculated using current date and DOB (from CSV file). Please suggest how to find age in a pipeline activity from this file and store in database. Thanks

Comment: `DateTime.Now - DoB`... or if your are using TSQL `getdate() - DoB` .... something like that

Comment: But where to specify this calculation in my data factory pipeline?

Comment: How do you import your file into your DB ?

Comment: I am using a copy activity in data factory. But obviously in this case, the Age column is being null as blob contains only name and DOB. So I need to find Age and put it along with other data from blob in database.

Comment: can you just create a computed column in your SQL DB ?

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-data-transformation-activities/

Comment: No, it is not allowed, as database structure is not open to us.

Comment: Especially you can use a store procedure to calculate what you need https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-stored-proc-activity/

Comment: or custom activities https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/

Comment: Yes, i have use stored procedures, but that makes the data factory messy

Comment: what do you mean by messy ?

Comment: For this, i have to first use a copy activity to transfer data from blob to sql database (i.e. 1 pipeline and 2 datasets) further, I call stored procedure and output data to database (1 pipeline activity and 1 dataset). So, there is a Sql dataset being copied 2 times. I was thinking if there could be any way to calculate age in the copy activity instead of using 2 pipeline activities,

Comment: Or can you modify your file (add the age) before sending it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to go about doing this is by invoking a stored procedure on the destination (Azure SQL DB) from within the copy activity. You can pass the ADF system variable 'WindowStart' as a parameter to the stored procedure and within the stored procedure the age calculation can be done. This link (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink) would help.

Thanks, Harish